# Stack Trace completely missing from rails server in git bash terminal for windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, git, bash

I can start a local server and view my rails app's pages from it just fine, but no stack trace whatsoever appears in the terminal.  This only happens when I use the git bash for windows, however, and it seems to work fine from the windows cmd.

I am running Windows 10, Ruby 2.2.3, Rails 4.2.4, and Git 2.6.4.  Here is a screenshot of exactly what the terminal shows when I start the server and connect to the site's home page.
Has anyone seen this before?
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cyUX.png)

If it helps, here is the config/environment/development.rb code:

```
Rails.application.configure do
# Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

Comment: That screenshot looks totally fine to me. Your application might be configured log everything into an log file (`log/development.log` for example) or it might have set an log level that only logs errors (search for `config.log_level`) in your app.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I do see the stack trace appear in the log file.  I posted the config file for dev above.  The `log_level` is just the default.  Also, since the stack trace appears in the normal windows cmd, I think it has something to do with git bash and not rails itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by using an older version of git bash for windows.  I installed 1.9.5, which works fine and prints the stack trace as expected.  It seems to have been a problem specific to git 2.x.
If anyone finds a better solution, please post.